# Trying to add yes/no vba message box into an existing working macro

Tags: excel, vba

I currently have a macro that works amazing well in Excel, but I'm wanting to add a Yes/No question into the VBA prior to starting the macro. The problem is I've tried several methods and looked for a way to make this work, and adding a simple one-line conditional statement isn't enough for what I'm trying to do.

Essentially, if the user selects Yes, I need the current macro to run in its entirety, but if they select No, I need a message box to popup stating they will need to complete the verification steps to continue. The current code (without any yes/no statement) is as follows... can anyone help?

```vb
Sub Submit_Details()
    Dim shDrug As Worksheet
    Dim shLogging As Worksheet
    Dim iCurrentRow As Integer
    Dim sDrugName As String
    
    Set shLogging = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Logging")
    sDrugName = shLogging.Range("G11").Value
    Set shDrug = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(sDrugName)
    iCurrentRow = shDrug.Range("A" & Application.Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    
    With shDrug
        .Cells(iCurrentRow, 1) = Format([now()], "DD-MMM-YYYY HH:MM:SS")
        .Cells(iCurrentRow, 2) = shLogging.Range("G7")
        .Cells(iCurrentRow, 3) = shLogging.Range("G8")
        .Cells(iCurrentRow, 4) = shLogging.Range("G9")
        .Cells(iCurrentRow, 5) = shLogging.Range("G10")
        .Cells(iCurrentRow, 6) = shLogging.Range("G12")
        .Cells(iCurrentRow, 7) = shLogging.Range("G13")
    End With
    
    shLogging.Range("G7, G8, G9, G10, G11, G12, G13").Value = ""
    
    MsgBox "Data submitted successfully!"
End Sub
```

Comment: So what you are struggling with is putting one `if` inside another?

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but don't do this: `[now()]`. It's `Application.Evaluate("=NOW()")` and there is no reason to do it when you have [`Now`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/now-function).

Comment: `If MsgBox("[Your Message Here]", vbYesNo) = vbYes Then` your code `Else` [Another MsgBox telling them to do something] `End If`

Comment: `shLogging.Range("G7, G8, G9, G10, G11, G12, G13").Value` can be `shLogging.Range("G7:G13").Value`

Comment: I guess I'm struggling with where to put it in that thread.  I tried putting it after the "Sub Submit_Details()" prior to the "Dim shDrug As Worksheet" and tried to use the "If MsgBox(" = byes Then"  and then after the "MsgBox 'Data submitted successfully" used the Else statement, but at that point all it does is goes straight to the Else statement no matter if Yes or No is clicked.  {Side note: I've basically been trying to learn macros through videos/sites so it's all very new for me so several of the suggestions will definitely be updated in the current macro - thank you!}

Answer (score 0):

If you put this snippet first in the sub, it will get you started:

```
If MsgBox("Are you sure?", vbYesNo) <> vbYes Then
    Exit Sub
End If
```